# Как работать с Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Доброго времени суток!

Столкнулась с проблемой. Честно скажу, я новичок в программировании, но решилась записаться на ЕГЭ по информатике. Он проводится в новом формате. И, если понимаю, там будет установлено все "стандартно". Выбрала язык C++ (в школе когда-то учила, по ravesli занимаюсь сейчас, вроде нормально. Но писать пробовала в Visual Studio которая IDE полноценная, а не "редактор кода"), и выбрала недопоняв в списке Visual Studio Code. Привычной мне не было вообще. Были еще Code Blocks и DevC++, но в них и вовсе без бутылки не разобраться...

Суть вопроса, там будет установлена только Visual Studio Code (с дополнением C/C++ от MS). Как на этом работать без интернета и дополнительных плагинов? Она даже Hello World не компилирует! Помогите пожалуйста, подскажите, может я что-то не так понимаю, или она работает только с тучей расширений в дополнении (которые мне не дадут на ЕГЭ скачать, соответственно)?

Comment: А что пробного не будет?

Comment: В любом случае тренируйтесь на блокноте. Если на блокноте осилите то vs code пройдет на ура

Comment: Я выпускник прошлых лет. Мне такой роскоши не предоставят(

Comment: Блокнот тогда и не бойтесь. Все будет хорошо

Comment: В блокноте - не вариант. Там требуют готовый рабочий алгоритм и ввод в графу "ответ" итог выполнения программы, с заданными данными. Это просто так не посчитать и тд.

Comment: Я вот работаю на vs code. И поверьте это не зря называют навороченным блокнотом, а не ide

Comment: Вы все правильно понимаете, она работает только после установки кучи расширений. Даже собственно компилятор придется ставить сторонний.

Comment: Начните с блокнота это сложно но поверьте потом vs code вам покажется навороченным суперкаром

Comment: Поймите вам нужно всего создать файл в блокноте и протащить его через компилятор которого нет в vscode

Comment: У автора вопрос не как набирать текст программы, а как эту программу откомпилировать и запустить. А вы ей блокнот советуете

Comment: Да и я советую взять простой файл и протащить его через компилятор. И не думать о vs code. На котором автор зациклился

Comment: Я не зациклилась на VS Code. Я зациклилась на том, что у меня будет на экзамене чистый комп, с MS Office и VS Code (с плагином C/C++). Все. Смысл мне от этого редактора кода, если там задания построены так, что считать "вручную" я могу дольше, чем длится экзамен. А мне надо решить задачу, используя вводные данные, написать алгоритм, скомпилировать, увидеть ответ и вписать его в бланк. Все упирается в то, что может ли мне помочь в этом данный редактор кода (без допов) или это тоже самое, что писать в блокноте или код на листочке.

Comment: Я не знаю откуда выдрать инфу, не знаю будет ли там компилятор (в дополнение) в доступе.

p.s. я иногда вечером (когда лениво) продолжаю уроки на телефоне, пишу просто в сообщениях сама себе текстом код. Утром с компа вбиваю в VS и проверяю, работает или нет. Навык "писать на листочке" и "писать в txt" есть. Только смысл от него, если на экзамене требуют результат выполнения программы, а не ход ее решения.

Comment: Думаю немешало бы взять пару тройку занятий у репетитора. Как никак они в этой среде крутятся

Comment: Вы не понимаете суть моего вопроса. Хорошо, пример. У вас есть чистый комп без инета, VS Code, файл с заданием, где указано 10к символов и нужно найти в них самую длинную последовательность символов, при которой нет повторения 2х одинаковых символов подряд (извините за тавтологию). И кроме этого задания у вас еще 26 и на все 4 часа. Как вы решите эту задачу с помощью блокнота и без компилятора? нововведения этого года. потому и узнавала о возможностях VS Code (раз ее указали как среду разработки в списке).

Comment: Ну так нам откуда знать будет ли там компилятор?

Comment: Вот я и не понимала, может я тупая, или лыжи не едут. Почему средой разработки назвали редактор кода. Просмотрела за 2 дня миллион видео как с ним работать и поняла, что без плагинов это обычный блокнот. Потому и возник вопрос, может это я не увидела там встроенного компилятора. Мне уже ответили на этот вопрос, спасибо. Буду стучать разработчикам ЕГЭ на почту, узнавать о доп. ПО

Comment: Научитесь компилировать через командную строку. Тогда даже если VS Code начнет быковать, то сможете откомпилить файл напрямую.

Comment: Когда я писал ЕГЭ, там не то что блокнота, и компа то не было. Пишешь без всяких компиляторов на бумажке весь код, и не дай бог хоть где-то очепятку допустишь, минус баллы уже) А ведь это было не так уж давно, в 2015 :S

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp
подробная инструкция по настройке VS Code для полноценной работы

Answer (score 0):

Вам будет необходим компилятор. Сама VSCode по дефолту не сильно отличается от блокнота с автодополнением. Даже если есть расширение типа Cpp compiler, оно лишь дает интерфейс к какой-то командной утилите, которая должна быть установлена отдельно. Вот документация к вашему расширению, тут в том числе даны примеры установки компиляторов.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_install-a-compiler